# Как написать простую функцию добавления и удаления класса у элемента стрелочными функциями на ecmo-6

Tags: ecmascript-6

Как написать простую функцию добавления и удаления класса у элемента стрелочными функциями на ecmo 6?
Суть в том чтобы применять именно ecmo 6, чтобы спокойно переделывать функции из js 5 в ecmo 6.

Comment: точно так же как и обычными функциями.

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести пример такого кода?

Answer (score 1):

В общем я сделал вот так и это работает

```
menuButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    menuButton.classList.toggle('on');
});
```